# Write data in NFC tag with the provided data

Tags: android, tags, nfc, ndef

Can anyone please tell me how to write the following info into an NFC tag?

Is there any tool or app to write in this format?

```
 +------+------+------+------+------+--------------------------+
 | NDEF Message= 3(0x03) (1 byte)                              |        
 +-------------------------------------------------------------+
 | LEGTH=69 (0x45)(1 byte)                                     |
 +------+------+------+------+------+--------------------------+
 | MB=1 | ME=0 | CF=0 | SR=1 | IL=0 | TNF=2 (MIME type record) |(0x92)
 +------+------+------+------+------+--------------------------+
 | TYPE LENGTH=09 (0x90)                                       |
 +-------------------------------------------------------------+
 | PAYLOAD LENGTH=17 (0x11)(1 byte)                            |
 +-------------------------------------------------------------+
 | TYPE="co/info"  (9 byte)                                    |
 +-------------------------------------------------------------+
 | PAYLOAD="bd://aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff" (55 byte)                  |
 +------+------+------+------+------+--------------------------+
 | MB=0 | ME=1 | CF=0 | SR=1 | IL=0 | TNF=4 (External type)    |
 +------+------+------+------+------+--------------------------+
 | TYPE LENGTH=15 (0x0F)                                       |
 +-------------------------------------------------------------+
 | PAYLOAD LENGTH=22 (0x16)                                    |
 +-------------------------------------------------------------+
 | TYPE="android.com:pkg"                                      |
 +-------------------------------------------------------------+
 | PAYLOAD="com.your.app.package"                              |
 +-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: Stackoverflow is about programming and not the right place to get recommendations for tools and existing apps.

Nevertheless, I believe that parts of this question could be valuable for Android developers as well.

What you show in your question is an NDEF message. This NDEF message consists of a MIME type record and an external type record.

The MIME type record contains the MIME type "co/info" (atucally a malformed MIME type as it does not follow the corresponding RFC!) with the data value "bd://aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff". In an Android app, you could generate this record using the method `NdefRecord.createMime()`:

```
NdefRecord r1 = NdefRecord.createMime("co/info",
                                      "bd://aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff".getBytes("US-ASCII"));
```

The NFC Forum external type record is an Android Application Record (type name "android.com:pkg") for the application package "com.your.app.package". You can generate that record using the `NdefRecord.createApplicationRecord()` method:

```
NdefRecord r2 = NdefRecord.createApplicationRecord("com.your.app.package");
```

You can then assemble those two records into an NDEF message:

```
NdefMessage msg = new NdefMessage(r1, r2);
```

Finally, you can write that message to an NFC tag (assuming that you already obtained a tag handle from an NFC tag discovery intent and that the tag is already formatted for NDEF):

```
Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tag);
ndef.connect();
ndef.writeNdefMessage(msg);
ndef.close();
```

Comment: Thank you so much..sorry for the late reply, i was stuck with some other high priority task.

Comment: it wored for me..but it writes the data at [00] in memory and continues, but i want it to start write from [04]. can any one help me how to do it?

Comment: @Bharani The above code writes the data exactly where it is supposed to be stored on an NFC Forum tag (e.g. starting at block 4 on a Type 2 tag). Moreover, it wraps the data in whatever data structures are necessary for that tpye of tag (e.g. NDEF Message TLV on Type 2 tag).

Comment: ya even ithought write by default it starts writing from 4 th block but after writing, i could see it starts from 1 block.I am using MIFARE ISO 14443 NTAG213 TYpe A tag. Couldn't figure out what's the cause?